# Chrome extension getting disabled after restart

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I've been happily using the [Auto HD For Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/koiaokdomkpjdgniimnkhgbilbjgpeak) Google Chrome extension. Unfortunately, whenever I launch Chrome I discover the extension has been disabled, and I need to manually enable it. The extension will remain enabled as long as I don't shut down Chrome, but when I do it reverts back to being disabled.

I've found [this related thread in the Chrome support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5dfb357b5b647930&hl=en), but it wasn't particularly helpful. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I'm using Chrome 13.0.782.220 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it sorted itself out on Chrome 15, so I guess that's a sort of a solution.